# Firestore Rules with Nuxt with Nuxt/firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

Deploying a public website that reads from Firestore. Using Nuxt with SSR and @nuxtjs/firebase.

I have a cloud function this is currently able to write to the DB via the default service account. My understanding is that security rules get overwritten by any app using the default service account.

What is the best approach to limit read to only my Nuxt app?

The documentation from [nuxt/firebase](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/service-options/auth) says that service account integration is not production ready.

Is there a simpler way to approach this?

Current Security Rules are as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write, delete: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Current folder structure is as follows:

```
/Root
   /plugins
      /firebase.js
   /pages
      /index.vue
```

Contents of firebase.js file are as follows:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  const config = {
    apiKey: ,
    authDomain: ,
    projectId: ,
    storageBucket: ,
    messagingSenderId: ,
    appId: ,
    measurementId: ,
  }
  firebase.initializeApp(config)
  firebase.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })
}

const fireDb = firebase.firestore()
export { fireDb }
```

Comment: "What is the best approach to limit read to only my Nuxt app?" You only want your cloud functions to respond to requests made from the Nuxt app ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj- i don't want to interrupt my cloud function's ability to read/write. But otherwise yes, I want to limit access to my DB to only allow my Nuxt app to read data. The DB hosts data that i will display publicly on my website. There is no user auth on the site at this time.

Comment: Have you checked [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web) ?

Comment: This is the first I've of it @Dharmaraj. Looks like that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!